# Jenkins pipeline manually deploy options

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am currently using Jenkins pipeline to **build** -> **unit test** -> **deploy to test server** and **run automated test**. After the automated test succeed I want to manually deploy the application to production. Is there any way I can create a manual button or (other options) to be able to manually deploy to production environment?

Comment: [`input`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input) is the main supported step for that right now, but there are many ways to achieve this.

Comment: Hi mkobit, thanks for your answer. I tried input, but when I abort the process, the whole pipeline fails.

Comment: @Skyx I also dislike the behavior. You could have a "yes / no" input field theoretically, but I have an implementation [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-infrastructure/jenkins-pipeline-global-library-chefci/blob/9280da96433f9ca4576546988b422306401771c6/src/org/typo3/chefci/helpers/JenkinsHelper.groovy#L67-L109) that does not fail the pipeline on abort and also allows to set a timeout.

Comment: @mkobit "input" is waiting for the user's input to finish the build, which is not exactly what the question is about. Since you claim that there are many ways to achieve that, could you please provide 1 or 2 more?

Comment: @WallTearer `input` is more of the built-in pipeline way to do it. When I wrote _"many ways to achieve this"_, I was thinking of other options through Jenkins like another Job that only deploys, another repository that controls deployments (manual pull requests there, but automated deploy), or some other mechanism not entirely built around the Jenkins built-in `input` step.